# How to use redux-saga with server side rendering?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I'm new in react, redux and saga. Here is a dicsussion (https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/issues/13) about using redux saga with server side rendering. But I didn't understand anything. It's so complicated. Really. Can anyone show minimal working example of redux-saga with server side rendering? I didn't find that. It would be more useful and understandalbe than long discussion on Github. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

Quite late to the party but for the curious, redux-saga has an example of Server side rendering in its example folder : 
https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/tree/master/examples/real-world